# ParseFile.saveInBackground() never get called

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com to save some image from my android application
so I use that code:

```
byte[] b = UriToBytesArray(fileUri); // b.length is 239493
ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("photo.jpg", b);
parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saved in background");
    }
});
```

But the callback is never called,
if I use `.save()` instead it save the file to Parse
and even more strange, if I use `.save()` juste before `.saveInBackground(...)` the callback is called (that is not a solution of course)

I read the doc again and again but I can't find what is wrong: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#files-classes

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps using the other overloaded method with ProgressCallback will give more insight?

Comment: The other method with the ``ProgressCallback()`` doesn't give more result (both callback are not called)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in this specific scenario the `Parse.initialize` code was not called and that is why it failed (but without any error message)

Comment: I made sure that the Parse.initialize code was called, in my app it was not the case because I added into the Application.java file but did not explicite that file in the manifest